# Largest Occurrence Count

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Im new to programming and am stumped on this problem, Ive tried a few different ways with no success.

> Implement (source code) a program (name it LargestOccurenceCount) that read from the user positive non-zero integer values, finds the largest value, and counts it occurrences. Assume that the input ends with number 0 (as sentinel value to stop the loop). The program should ignore any negative input and should continue to read user inputs until 0 is entered. The program should display the largest value and number of times it appeared

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0;
int array[] = null;

while ((num = reader.nextInt()) != 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer (0 to quit): ");
    num = reader.nextInt();
    array[num] = num;
}
```

Sample run 1:

> Enter positive integers (0 to quit): 3 4 5 -9 4 2 5 1 -5 2 5 0
>
> Largest value:   5
>   Occurrences:     3 times

The program should output the largest value entered and the number of times it was entered before 0 is entered.

Comment: The largest number in that sample run is indeed 5 and it does occur 3 times. What is the problem?

Comment: You'll probably want to include some of your attempts--SO isn't really a homework writing stop-and-shop. What specifically is giving you problems? Iterating? Storing the counts? Something else?

Comment: I'm guessing that's sample output given in the homework, not your output.  Your code looks like it'll throw NPE if it gets that far.  You need to give us your output, we aren't just going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
// part of reading the values from command line and 
// putting them into this array is omitted
int[] array = ...;
int biggest = 0;
int occurance = 0;
for(int num : array) {
    if(num > biggest) {
        biggest = num;
        occurance = 0;
    }
    if(num == biggest) {
        occurance++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Biggest number %s occured %s times.%n", biggest, occurance);
```

As mentioned in the comment, I've omitted the part where you read the values from the command line, as that doesn't seem to be your problem.

---

Another solution which does the reading directly, and without the need of an array and all inside one loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int biggest = 0;
int occurance = 0;
int num;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    // this may throw an Exception if the users input is not a number
    num = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    if(num == 0) {
        // user entered a 0, so we exit the loop
        break;
    }
    if(num > biggest) {
        biggest = num;
        occurance = 1;
    } else if(num == biggest) {
        biggest++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("Biggest number %s occured %s times.%n", biggest, occurance);
```

Comment: Hopefully you'll be there when they take their test, too. IMO homework questions should *not* be answered directly. It defeats the purpose of homework.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I was making this much harder than it needed to be and trying to use things outside of my scope.

Answer (score 0):

Split your problem into two parts.
1. Find the largest value

```
int findLargest(int[] array) {
  assert array.length > 0;
  int result = array[0];
  for (int element : array) {
    if (element > result) {
      result = element;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

2. ... and find it in the array

```
int countOccurences(int[] array, int value) {
  int occurences = 0;
  for (int element : array) {
    if (element == value) {
      occurences++;
    }
  }
  return occurences;
}
```

Note that array should have at least one element;

Comment: Why should array be required to have at least one value? Your first method unnecessarily checks the first element twice.

Comment: That's it. I wondered if anyone will notice one unnecessary operation. The easiest solution of this problem is to use Stream and max() function.

Comment: Hopefully you'll be there when they take their test, too. IMO homework questions should *not* be answered directly. It defeats the purpose of homework.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no requirements to use array only, you can use `ArrayList` for storing user inputs

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
while ((num = reader.nextInt()) != 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer (0 to quit): ");
    num = reader.nextInt();
    list.add(num);
}
```

Then if you are good with stream api, there is quite concise solution:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Long> lastEntry = list.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, counting()))
            .lastEntry();

System.out.println(
        "Largest value: " + lastEntry.getKey() +
        " Occurrences: " + lastEntry.getValue() + " times");
```

Comment: Hopefully you'll be there when they take their test, too. IMO homework questions should *not* be answered directly. It defeats the purpose of homework.

Comment: @DaveNewton I hope he can figure this code out, not just copy/past.. But in general you are right. I'll take it into account.. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think i was making it more complicated than it needed to be.